# Is this bash variable a valid IP v4 or 6 address?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ip

I have a bash (v5.2 from latest Debian testing/bookworm apt) variable called `TARGET`. How can I check if the contents is a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address, rather than something like `ERROR`?

Comment: Valid Syntax or valid in the sense of "host/network exists with the address"?

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a simple validation by using bash regular expressions to see if the variable matches the expected format:

```
is_ipv4_address() {
  [[ $1 =~ [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3} ]]
}
```

Using the above function, we can run this script:

```
for data in 1.2 1.2.3 1.2.3.4; do
  echo -n "$data: "
  is_ipv4_address "$data" && echo yes || echo no
done
```

And get as output:

```
1.2: no
1.2.3: no
1.2.3.4: yes
```

This is a "loose" validation: that is, `999.999.999.999` matches the pattern but isn't a valid address. If you need a more complete solution, there is a [Linux Journal article](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/validating-ip-address-bash-script) on this topic .

---

IPv6 is a bit more complicated: it would be simple to match the fully expanded form, but that by itself is no good since we can collapse zeroes.

We could start with something like this:

```
is_ipv6_address() {
  [[ $1 =~ ^([0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}:){0,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}$ ]]
}
```

As with the previous solution, this is a loose match; this **will** match things that aren't actually ipv6 addresses, but it might be just fine depending on your needs. Here are some test cases:

```
testcases=(
1.2.3.4
2001:foo
"i am not an ip address"
2001:0000:3238:DFE1:0063:0000:0000:FEFB
2001:0000:3238:DFE1:63:0000:0000:FEFB
2001:0000:3238:DFE1:63::FEFB
2001:0:3238:DFE1:63::FEFB
2c:f0:5d:c9:12:a9
)

for testcase in "${testcases[@]}"; do
  echo -n "$testcase: "
  is_ipv6_address "$testcase" && echo yes || echo no
done
```

The above outputs:

```
1.2.3.4: no
2001:foo: no
i am not an ip address: no
2001:0000:3238:DFE1:0063:0000:0000:FEFB: yes
2001:0000:3238:DFE1:63:0000:0000:FEFB: yes
2001:0000:3238:DFE1:63::FEFB: yes
2001:0:3238:DFE1:63::FEFB: yes
2c:f0:5d:c9:12:a9: yes
```

So we can see that it matches valid ipv6 address formats, rejects obviously wrong formats, but matches MAC addresses. There's room for improvement, but hopefully this gives you a place to start.

Comment: What about IPv6 ?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Could probably do something like `is_ipv6() { [[ "$1" =~ ^([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}$ ]] || [[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9a-fA-F:]*::[0-9a-fA-F:]*$ ]]; }` to check for full-length IPv6 addresses and abbreviated ones in two parts. (The regexes there would still accept an overlong address with `::` or something with `:::` in the middle, but at least the IPv6 vs. MAC address mixup wouldn't be there.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Debian package called `ipcalc-ng`, which contains an executable to check IP-addresses for validity.

```
$ ipcalc-ng -c ::xx; echo $?
ipcalc-ng: bad IPv6 address: ::xx
1
$ ipcalc-ng -c ::1; echo $?
0
```